# I've been seeing good movies or I've been watching good movies?

Tags: verbs, present-participles, ing

what would you rather say? Which one is correct?
Thanks,Herman.

Comment: Watching some good movies. However have a look at http://ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The words "seeing" and "watching" can have subtly different meanings.  "Seeing good movies" might imply that you have seen them advertised in a magazine or online without having actually watched them.  "Watching" has a more specific meaning in that it requires concentration and to that effect is probably the word to use.

So ultimately do you want to say that you have seen that there are some good movies around at the moment or that you have actually been watching some good movies?

You could improve the grammar of the statements, but the question seems to be more about the usage of "seeing" versus "watching".

Answer (score 0):

They're both grammatical but neither of them sound very nice. You wouldn't hear a native speaker say either of those.

You wouldn't use the perfect tense to say either, you'd normally use the simple past. "I've recently seen some good movies."

I've added two adverbs here "recently" makes it clear that you're not talking about the movies you've seen throughout your life - which, in your defense, and to some extent, using the auxilliary verb "been" does itself. Without. Determiners play a big part in English, and they hugely help encourage specificity.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the perfect tense. Adding "some" does make the expression sound more natural, though. To me, "I've been seeing some good movies" feels more natural than "I've recently seen some good movies," at least in conversation.